# Differentiating between objects without explicitly stating them in the class

Tags: java

```
 /**
     * Add a student to this school.
     * @param student The student to be added.
     */
    public void addStudent(Member student)
    {   
        students.add(student);
    }


 public void setTeacher(Member teacher)
    {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
```

I have two subclasses of member called student and teacher. I don't want the user to be able to add the teacher to the student list, or set a student as the teacher. Is there a way of doing this without using instanceof? I just don't like what my class diagram looks like when i use it haha.

This is homework by the way. I think I've completed it all but was just interested to know whether there is a simple solution to this. I just want to avoid explicitly stating Student or Teacher in this class.

Comment: Why not just declare your function to take the specific subtype as an argument?

Comment: "I just want to avoid explicitly stating Student or Teacher in this class." So you don't think `addStudent` or `setTeacher` explicitly states a student or a teacher? Set the parameter types correctly and you won't have a problem.

Comment: *I don't want the user to be able to add the student to the student list, or set a student as the teacher* - then you should have `Teacher teacher` and `List<Student> students` instead of  `Member teacher` and `List<Member> students`.

Comment: For example `public void addStudent(Student student)`

Answer (score 1):

Well one solution is to use GetClass() method or maybe [Visitor Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/instanceof-operator-and).

But if you want to avoid this why you use `Polymorphism` at first place? Use in method instance of **Teacher or Student** as strong type.

```
public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher)
    {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, this was my working solution anyway so I think I will keep it as it is :) .